# Which files/folders can be safely git ignored while setting up Sonarqube server Git Repository?

Tags: git, sonarqube

I want to use sonarqube to statically analyse my code locally and want to share sonarqube server related details(login credentials, projects etc) with my team.I also don't intend to deploy the sonarqube server. In order to share server related details, I created a git repo for sonarqube server but lot of files are getting generated, deleted when starting server or analysing code. So my question here is which files/folders can be safely git ignored while setting up Sonarqube server Git Repository?

My Sonarqube Server Folder Structure looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to experiment, but you can ignore:

- any "temp" folder
- any folder with generated content

To determine those folder, I would start versioning a SonarQube server before the first start, then check the delta between that initial state and one where the server has analyzed a project.